# Java generics for Enum types

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard, enumeration

I am trying to write a Java class, one part of which requires a mapping of the values of an unknown enum to another class.  My class contains a field `private Map<? extends Enum, Unit> myMap` and is initialized with a factory method `createMyClass`:

```
public static MyClass <T extends Enum> myClass createMyClass(Class<T> x) {
    MyClass theClass = new MyClass() //constructor is private
    //...
    myMap = new HashMap<T, Unit>();
    for(T t : x.getEnumConstants())
        myMap.put(t, theClass.new Unit(t));
    //...
}
```

The class `Unit` is (and needs to be, as far as I can tell) an inner class of `MyClass`.  When I put this into NetBeans it complains with this message:

> method `put` in interface `java.util.Map<K,V>` cannot be applied to given types
>   required: capture #4 of `? extends java.lang.Enum`, `MyClass.Unit`
>   found: `T`, `MyClass.Unit`

I understand (or at least I think I do) how the Collections need to be very careful about wildcard usage to preserve type safety, but I can't think of how `T extends Enum` fails to match `? extends Enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `Map<? extends Enum, Unit>` means is "The key is some specific class that extends Enum, but I don't known which one". And since you don't know which class it is, you cannot add anything to such a Map, you can only get elements from it and be certain they are `Enum`s.

You should probably just declare that field as  `Map<Enum, Unit>` - it will allow all `Enum` subclasses just fine.

This seems to be the most common misunderstanding about Java enums by a huge margin - people see that `?` wildcard and think they have to use it to allow subclasses.

Comment: The reason why I changed it to `? extends Enum` was that leaving it as `Enum` produced another error saying that `T` was an `incompatible type` with `Enum` and recommending that I use a cast.  Since casts like this seem suspicious I tried using `? extends`. As a supplementary question should I have to cast `HashMap<T,Unit>` to `HashMap<Enum,Unit>`?

Comment: @Actorclavilis: I think the cause of your problems is the fact that Enum is itself a generic class. Take a look at EnumMap, it will probably make things easier and certainly be faster.

Comment: along those lines, declaring `T` as `<T extends Enum<T>>` would fix that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your method declaration to:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> MyClass createMyClass(Class<T> x) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [Generics Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). It explains why this doesn't work in section 4 (Wildcards).

As far as I understand, *? extends Enum* can be *any* enum, not just a *T* or subclass of T.